# With istio circuit breaker (OutlierDetection), can default error response be configured?

Tags: kubernetes, istio, circuit-breaker

I'm using k8s, rest apis, and istio system. And I try to attach DestinationRule OutlierDetection infront of services as circuit breaker.

My Quetion is this.

> If every upstream of host goes down, can make istio return some configured status and response?

Comment: Istio returns various status codes and error messages in envoy proxy logs, status 503 means that upstream hosts are down. From your description I believe you are interested in configuring custom status codes but it is not possible to customize status codes in Istio. To assist you further in a better way, could you brief about your query/architecture in detail.<br>